# What to do with Medical Transcript dataset?

Tags: database, dataset

I have this MT Dataset, what can be done with such dataset, as a Data scientist, what questions can be asked regarding this dataset, what can be the yields, what to analyze, etc.

So far I thought to make a classification on age, gender.

To find the reasons why patients undergo, surgery, allergy tests, etc. What else can be done with it?

[image]

Comment: Hi Umer. As interesting as the question is, it is opinion-based and thus is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. We prefer specific programming-based questions that have a smaller range of possible correct answers.

Comment: @halfer Thank You, I have found a solution for it.

Comment: Great. I would encourage you to delete it if you can - it is likely to be automatically deleted anyway, once it is put on hold. Your answer for this is only going to fit your needs, but the answers we want to see here need to be useful for many people.